# jQuery, .each function question

Tags: jquery

I have following jQuery `.each loop`:

```
$('.table-data tbody tr td').each( function(index) {

    $('.table-data tbody tr td' + ':nth-child(' + index + ')' ).addClass( 'nth-' + index );


});
```

The problem is that it will work, but the last element of the `.table-data tbody tr td'` will not get a class. Why?

Is this because `index` is 0 based? How to make it loop for `index` + 1 time?

Comment: $(this) is equal to $('.table-data tbody tr td' + ':nth-child(' + index + ')' )

Comment: @JapanPro - yes, it took me a second to work that out - for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to drill down to the current element using the index, it's easier than that!

```
$(".table-data tbody td").each(function(index){
    $(this).addClass("nth-" + index);
});
```

To renumber the TD elements *within* each row, try this.

```
$(".table-data tbody tr").each(function(index){
    $(this).find("td").each(function(index){
        $(this).addClass("nth-" + index);
    });
});
```

OR, if you want to be a bit cleverer, this...

```
$(".table-data tbody td").each(function(){
    $(this).addClass("n-" + $(this).index());
});
```

See this in action: http://jsbin.com/usaqix

Comment: `$(this).addClass("nth-" + ++index );` will be perfect in my example! Very clever! thanks!

Comment: How to make it count from `0 in every row`? Do I have to put this in double `.each`?

Comment: double `.each` look like the easy way - but not most pro programic. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Inside the "each" $(this) represents the current element. The .index() method returns the position of an element relative to its siblings - in the case of the jsbin example a set of three TD elements inside a TR (see http://api.jquery.com/index/).

Answer (score 0):

The nth child starts on 1, so yes, your zero based index won't work correctly on it. You'll need to do index+1 where you use the index variable - but it will iterate the right number of times.